# How do I add pagination?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to rewrite part of my code that shows a table to be paginated so that if there are more than X records to display on a separate page. I want to rewrite the code using MySQLi but i haven't figured out out to use the store result function yet.

How to I fix the errors with the pagination code below? and use MYSQLi since four of the functions in my current code are deprecated

This is the old code that simply Displays a table which works.

```
<?php  

    $username = "some username";
    $password = "some password";
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $databasename = "some database";

    //connection to the database
        $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
        @mysqli_select_db($databasename,$dbhandle);

    //select a database to work with
        $selected = mysql_select_db("mydeos_calendar",$dbhandle) 
        or die("Could not select mydeos_calendar");

    //execute the SQL query and return records
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appointments ");
        $num=mysql_numrows($result);

    mysql_close();

    echo"<br><b><center>All Appointments</center></b><br><br>";

    // see if any rows were returned 
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 

    // print them one after another 
        echo "<table cellpadding=10 cellspacing=3 border=1 class=sortable>"; 
        echo "<tr><th>Date/Time</th><th>LEP</th> <th>Language</th> <th>Insurance</th><th>Nature</th><th>Duration</th><th>With</th><th>Vendor</th><th>Status</th><th>Appointment Type</th><th>Actions</th></tr>"; 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
    require "appointmentrows.php";

        echo '<td><a href="something">Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="something">Delete</a></td>';
        echo "</tr>"; } 
            echo "</table>"; } 
        else { 

    // print status message 
    echo "No Appointments Found!"; 
    } 

    $i=0;
    while ($i < $num) { 

    $appointment=mysql_result($result,$i,"appointment");
    $nature=mysql_result($result,$i,"nature");
    $duration=mysql_result($result,$i,"duration");
    $status=mysql_result($result,$i,"status");
    $language=mysql_result($result,$i,"language");
    $lep=mysql_result($result,$i,"lep");
    $vendor=mysql_result($result,$i,"vendor");
    $insurance=mysql_result($result,$i,"insurance");
    $client=mysql_result($result,$i,"client");
    $invoiceformat=mysql_result($result,$i,"invoiceformat");
    $appointmenttype=mysql_result($result,$i,"appointmenttype");
    $i++;
    }

?>
```

Here is the new code with pagination but I am not getting and results and see No Appointments Found! and the following errors.

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Warning: mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

```
<?php

    $username = "some username";
    $password = "some password";
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $databasename = "some database";

    //connection to the database
        $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
        @mysqli_select_db($databasename,$dbhandle);

    $tbl_name="appointments";       //your table name
    // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
    $adjacents = 3;

    /* 
       First get total number of rows in data table. 
       If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
    */
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name ";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "pagination.php";     //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 10;                                //how many items to show per page
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = "SELECT appointment, nature, duration, status, language, lep, vendor, insurance, client, appointmenttype FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $num=mysql_numrows($result);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">� previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">� previous</span>"; 

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next �</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next �</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
?>

    <?php
        if (mysql_fetch_array($result) > 0) { 
        echo "<table cellpadding=10 cellspacing=3 border=1 class=sortable>"; 
        echo "<tr><th>Date/Time</th><th>LEP</th> <th>Language</th> <th>Insurance</th><th>Nature</th><th>Duration</th><th>With</th><th>Vendor</th><th>Status</th><th>Appointment Type</th><th>Actions</th></tr>"; 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        // Your while loop here
            require "appointmentrows.php";

        echo '<td><a href="something">Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="something">Delete</a></td>';
        echo "</tr>"; } 
            echo "</table>"; } 
        else { 

    // print status message 
    echo "No Appointments Found!"; 
    } 

    $i=0;
    while ($i < $num) { 

    $appointment=mysql_result($result,$i,"appointment");
    $nature=mysql_result($result,$i,"nature");
    $duration=mysql_result($result,$i,"duration");
    $status=mysql_result($result,$i,"status");
    $language=mysql_result($result,$i,"language");
    $lep=mysql_result($result,$i,"lep");
    $vendor=mysql_result($result,$i,"vendor");
    $insurance=mysql_result($result,$i,"insurance");
    $client=mysql_result($result,$i,"client");
    $invoiceformat=mysql_result($result,$i,"invoiceformat");
    $appointmenttype=mysql_result($result,$i,"appointmenttype");
    $i++;
    }

    ?>

<?=$pagination?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Deal with the issues 1 at a time.  MySQL to MySQLi (procedural) is very similar, although some functions require your db connection as the first parameter.

Try a simplified example first to get the MySQLi functions working:

```
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
mysqli_select_db($databasename,$dbhandle);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$query = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
$pages = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: I know how to do the connection, query and fetch array but I can never get the num rows function to work and display the results. I also figured out what was causing the errors in my current code but the pagination is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_blog_posts($password,$username,$database_name,$page){
    try {
        $pdo_options[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND] = "SET NAMES utf8";
        $database_connexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database_name, $username, $password, $pdo_options);
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        die('Erreur lors la connexion à la BDD: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    if(isset($page) and $page >= 0){        // That bug ! With the empty function, int(0) is considred to be empty, so It did not want to get into the loop. Damn.
        $page = (int)$page;
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM billets";
        $result = $database_connexion->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();
        $number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
        // Calculate the number of the last page
        $rows_per_page = 5;
        $last_page = ceil($number_of_rows/$rows_per_page);
        $page = (int)$page;
        if($page > $last_page){
            $page = $last_page;
        }
        if($page < 1){
            $page = 1;
        }
        try {
            // Now that whe have the limit, let's call our articles.
            $limite_sql_query = 'LIMIT '.($page - 1)* $rows_per_page.','.$rows_per_page;
            $final_query = "SELECT * FROM billets ORDER BY id DESC $limite_sql_query ";
            $reponse = $database_connexion->query($final_query);
            // For each article, we go in the looooooooooooop !
            while ($articles = $reponse->fetch()) {
                // Print your article here.
}
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
           echo("Error: ".$e)
}        if($page == 1){
            $next_page = $page+1;
            echo "</div> <div class='mc-floating'> <a class='mc-button mc-button-icon mc-clickable mc-button-raised mc-bg-blue mc-color-white' mc-action='next'  href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$next_page'></a> </div>";
        } else {
            echo "</div> <div class='mc-floating'> <a class='mc-button mc-button-icon mc-clickable mc-button-raised mc-bg-blue mc-color-white' mc-action='home' href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=1'></a> ";
            $prevpage = $page-1;
            echo "<a class='mc-button mc-button-icon mc-clickable mc-button-raised mc-bg-blue mc-color-white' mc-action='prev' href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$prevpage'></a> ";
            $next_page = $page+1;
            echo "<a class='mc-button mc-button-icon mc-clickable mc-button-raised mc-bg-blue mc-color-white' mc-action='next' href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$next_page'></a> </div>
            ";
        }
    $reponse->closeCursor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats not MySQLi.. ..thats PDO

Comment: I could recommend using PDO, it's more robust ;-)

Comment: So could I.. ..but that wasn't the question or the help that was asked for.

Comment: I would love to learn PDO but I am just barely learning MYSQLi and PDO seems far more time consuming considering my time constraints for this current project. Also all my other code is already using MySQLi so I like to keep consistency so once i learned PDO and found it more useful I would rewrite all the code.